# Trying the get the JSON Schema specification's example meta-schema to work

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to get to work the [meta-schema example in the the JSON Schema specification](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-example-meta-schema-with-vo).

I put the new main meta-schema into a file that I named **new-main-meta-schema.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/meta/general-use-example",
  "$dynamicAnchor": "meta",
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/core": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/applicator": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/validation": true,
    "https://example.com/vocab/example-vocab": true
  },
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/core"},
    {"$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/applicator"},
    {"$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/validation"},
    {"$ref": "https://example.com/meta/example-vocab"}
  ],
  "patternProperties": {
    "^unevaluated": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "localKeyword": {
      "$comment": "Not in vocabulary, but validated if used",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

That meta-schema references a new extension schema. I put it into a file that I named **extension-schema.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/meta/example-vocab",
  "$dynamicAnchor": "meta",
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://example.com/vocab/example-vocab": true
  },
  "type": ["object", "boolean"],
  "properties": {
    "minDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}",
      "format": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I created a schema that conforms to the new meta-schema. I put the schema into a file that I named **schema.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://example.com/meta/general-use-example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "departingGate": {"type": "string"},
        "minDate": "2023-08-07"
    }
}
```

Then I created an instance of the schema. I put the instance into a file that I named **instance.json**

```
{
   "departingGate": "Gate 26"
}
```

Does all that look correct?

Next, I wanted to validate **instance.json** against **schema.json** so I opened my browser to the [online JSON Schema validator tool Hyperjump](https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/). I copied the content of **new-main-meta-schema.json** into the schema portion of the online tool. Immediately the tool responded with this error message:

```
Error: Unrecognized vocabulary: https://example.com/vocab/example-vocab. You can define this vocabulary with the 'defineVocabulary' function.
```

Is there any way to run this example in Hyperjump's online schema validator? If not, is there an online schema validator that can run this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to run this example in Hyperjump's online schema validator?

With a couple tweaks, yes. Some parts of defining a custom dialect require code. Anything that requires code, can't be done in the online tool.

Your example creates a custom keyword called `minDate`. In order for the validator to know how to evaluate that keyword, you need to provide a [keyword implementation](https://github.com/hyperjump-io/json-schema#meta-schemas-keywords-vocabularies-and-dialects-experimental) in JavaScript (or TypeScript). You can't provide code online, but if your keyword is only an annotation (always validates to `true`), you can make the vocabulary that keyword is in optional and avoid having to write code.

Here's how you make the vocabulary optional.

```json
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/core": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/applicator": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/validation": true,
    "https://example.com/vocab/example-vocab": false // <-- This changed to false
  },
```

It's in the vocab meta-schema too. There's actually no reason to use `$vocabulary` here, so just remove it.

```json
  // Delete these lines
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://example.com/vocab/example-vocab": true
  },
```

Now it will work in the online validator. If you haven't figured it out yet, you can add additional tabs to the schemas panel using the `[+]` button. The first tab is always the entry point. That's where the schema you created will go. The dialect meta-schema and the vocabulary meta-schema will go in the "Schema 2" and "Schema 3" tabs that you open. WARNING: To avoid a bug, add the meta-schemas first before you paste your schema into the main Schema tab.

At this point you'll get an invalid schema error, because your schema isn't valid. I think you meant something like this,

```json
  "departureDate": { "minDate": "2023-08-07" } // <-- The `minDate` keyword needed to be inside a schema
```